# Which is the best software to use as proxy in LAN

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I am working in a IT office where [facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) is blocked and need to access **facebook website** as we have less work here.

Someone told me to use **proxy software** but not sure which one to use. Please help me.

Comment: If you need access to Facebook, contact your management or IT support and an exception can be made, almost all blocking software has a way to do it. We are not here to help you circumvent your employers security and policy, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Ultrasurf** software which is easy to configure and the guide is available in the [website](http://ultrasurf.us/).

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh!

If you are in IT you likely have some remote server somwhere.

You can use ssh -D portnumberofchoice someremoteserver

Then you can use a proxy setting in you browser by installing an extention (foxyproxy for example) and connect to localhost with the port you provided on a socks 5 proxy

example: `ssh -D 8080 10.0.0.200`  (this ip is just an example)

You proxy settings then would be server: 127.0.0.1 portnumber: 8080

If you have no server or external box available you can use a server from the many cloud providers. Some even let you spin up the server for a few minutes and only ask you to pay for the seconds it was active.